# Correr aplicación en segundo plano en java

Tags: java, jframe

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que mi `JFrame` se inicie en segundo plano en el `SystemTray`?

Tengo la clase `Notificacion` la cual hago:

```
    private JFrame parent;
    private PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();
    private final Image image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Notificacion.png")).getImage();
    private final TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "Notificacion.png", popup);
//para el Timer
    private Timer timer;
    ///////////////////////////
    SystemTray systemTray;
```

Constructor:

```
public Notificacion(JFrame frame) {
        this.parent = frame;
        instanciarTray();
        segundoPlano();
    }
```

Métodos `instanciarTray()` y `segundoPlano()`:

```
private void instanciarTray(){
        trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
        systemTray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
    }

    private void segundoPlano() {
        try {
            if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {
                systemTray.add(trayIcon);
                parent.setVisible(false);

                //Se inicia una tarea cuando se minimiza           
                if (timer != null) {
                    timer.cancel();
                }
                timer = new Timer();
                timer.schedule(new miTimerTask(), 2000, 5000);//Se ejecuta cada 5 segundos
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR);
        }
    }
```

Pero cuando inicia mi aplicación no se ejecuta en segundo plano, ¿qué estoy haciendo mal?

Desde el `JFrame` llamo a la clase de la siguiente forma:

```
Notificacion notificacion = new Notificacion(this);
```

Comment: Es necesario que se ejecute en el mismo hilo de ejecución?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITADO:

He estado investigando un poco y lo más lógico es tomar otra solución:
No crees un JFrame de inicio, simplemente añade un icono a la barra de tareas y, cuando el usuario pulse sobre el icono, entonces creas tu JFrame. Del mismo modo, destruye el JFrame cuando se pulse cerrar o minimizar. Te pongo un ejemplo completamente funcional, sólo tienes que modificar la parte en la que asigna la imagen del icono:

```
package gui;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.MenuItem;
import java.awt.PopupMenu;
import java.awt.SystemTray;
import java.awt.TrayIcon;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowStateListener;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static JFrame mainFrame;

    private static void showFrame() {
        mainFrame= new JFrame("Título de la ventana");
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setSize(300, 200);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        mainFrame.addWindowStateListener(new WindowStateListener() {

            @Override
            public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent arg0) {
                if (arg0.getNewState() == Frame.ICONIFIED) {
                    mainFrame.dispose();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        // Check the SystemTray support
        if (!SystemTray.isSupported()) {
            System.out.println("SystemTray no soportado");
            return;
        }
        final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();
        final TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(createImage("/icon.png", "Icono"));
        final SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

        // Create a popup menu components
        MenuItem aboutItem = new MenuItem("Abrir ventana");

        MenuItem exitItem = new MenuItem("Salir");

        // Add components to popup menu
        popup.add(aboutItem);
        popup.addSeparator();

        popup.add(exitItem);

        trayIcon.setPopupMenu(popup);

        try {
            tray.add(trayIcon);
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            System.out.println("TrayIcon could not be added.");
            return;
        }

        trayIcon.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Esto sale al hacer doble click en el icono");
            }
        });

        aboutItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                showFrame();
            }
        });

        exitItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                tray.remove(trayIcon);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    // Obtain the image URL
    protected static Image createImage(String path, String description) {
        URL imageURL = Main.class.getResource(path);

        if (imageURL == null) {
            System.err.println("Resource not found: " + path);
            return null;
        } else {
            return (new ImageIcon(imageURL, description)).getImage();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Lescano en que parte iría eso? En el constructor, dentro de mi método..

Comment: En el constructor debería valer, la idea es crear el JFrame minimizado

Comment: entiendo! Lo e probado pero lo que yo quiero no es eso, sino que el sistema se ejecute y valla directamente al SystemTray de mi barra de notificaciones me explico? Es una aplicación en segundo plano la que estoy desarrollando.

Comment: Y no se minimiza a la barra de tareas?

Comment: Se minimizado si, pero en la barra de tareas no en la barra de notificaciones, donde esta el reloj me explico? no se debería de ver en la barra de tarea, el código tuyo se muestra en la barra de tareas, o sea minimizado.

Comment: Ok, he editado mi respuesta con otro enfoque: no crear el JFrame a menos que sea necesario

Comment: Estimado colega estaba realizando mal lo que quería hacer, después de dos meses de desarrollar mi aplicación me di cuenta! No necesito un JFrame sino código y clases puro puro, me estuve matando hasta ahora queriendo ocultar el JFrame! Igualmente gracias por tu dedicación e interés..

Answer (score 0):

Generalmente se llama a `JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE)` o tambien a `System.exit` que cierran la aplicación. Pero en este caso tienes que llamar a `JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE)`:

> DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE -- The dispose-window default window close operation.
>
> DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE --The do-nothing default window close operation.
>
> EXIT_ON_CLOSE -- The exit application default window close operation.
>
> HIDE_ON_CLOSE -- The hide-window default window close operation.

Tal y como dice [la documentación de la interface WindowConstants](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/WindowConstants.html).

Comment: claro pero ese código que me brindas en tu respuesta es que al dar click en cerrar el JFrame se siga ejecutando en segundo plano pero lo que yo necesito es **Que ya se inicie la aplicación en segundo plano, que al ejecutar el proyecto arranque ya en segundo plano.** Me explico?

Comment: Pues llama a la función cuando inicie la aplicación, se me ocurre tal vez en el constructor justo después de `SystemTray.getSystemTray();`.

Comment: Incluso tal vez funcione si es la 1ra instrucción en el constructor.

Comment: Lo resolví de la siguiente manera, **Hice un proyecto totalmente de cero con una clase `Main` la cual no tenia mi proyecto original, Comencé basando todo mi proyecto en un JFrame y lo que yo quería era hacer una aplicación en segundo plano la cual correría en la barra de notificaciones del SO a si que presindi del JFrame, llame a mi clase madre `Notificacion`la cual llama a las demás clases, hace toda la lógica del sistema y guala! La magia se hizo.. Muchas gracias por su ayuda, se agradece.**