# ¿Cómo puedo correr un archivo .vbs desde Java?

Tags: java

He buscado diferentes formas pero nada hace que me corra mi archivo.

Lo que he hecho es un archivo .bat que ejecuta un backup a unos archivos importantes para mí. El problema es que me ejecuta la consola y no quiero. Deseo que se ejecute en segundo plano. Para ello investigué y encontré métodos creando un VB script para ocultarlo cuando se ejecute el batch, pero cuando intento ejecutarlo desde un programa Java que realizo (Minecraft - Plugin), no me lo ejecuta.

Nota: Ejecutarlo manualmente funciona, por lo que ni el batch ni el vbs están mal.

¿Qué podría hacer?

Acá dejo todos los métodos que intenté. Están separados por comentarios. Cada uno es un método diferente.

```js
String vbsfile = "C:\\Users\\geral\\Desktop\\run.vbs";
                    String executable = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\wscript.exe";
                    String cmdArr [] = {executable, vbsfile};
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArr);
                    //Este es otro método
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wscript C:\\Users\\geral\\Desktop\\run.vbs");
                    System.out.print("Listo, su programa debería ejecutarse.");
                    //Este es otro método
                    Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
                    desktop.open(new File("C:\\Users\\geral\\Desktop\\run.vbs"));
                    //Este es otro método
                    File backupfile = new File("C:\\Users\\geral\\OneDrive\\bad.py");
                    if(!Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                        System.out.print("No es soportado");
                        return;
                    }
                    Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
                    if(backupfile.exists()) {
                        desktop.open(backupfile);
                        warnings("info", "Se ha creado un backup del servidor.");
                    }
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Correr aplicación en segundo plano en java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/96464/correr-aplicaci%c3%b3n-en-segundo-plano-en-java)

Comment: Sin código es más difícil ayudarte. Saludos.}

Comment: Ya está. Lo separé por comentarios, los métodos que he utilizado.

Comment: Que tal algo como esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39062629/6999690 ?